# How to extract if-then rules from random forest in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I need to extract if-then rules corresponding to all trees in the random forest model.

I'm using RRF and inTress packages for the same.

```
library(RRF)
library(inTrees)
treeList <- RF2List(rf)
ruleExec <- extractRules(treeList,X,digits=4)
ruleExec <- unique(ruleExec)
```

This is giving me following output:-

```
X[,9]>0.599 & X[,10]>2.2447
```

I need the corresponding class predicted like:-

```
If X[,9]>0.599 & X[,10]>2.2447 then Class1
```

Comment: @jogo it's giving me around 2000 rules without corresponding class.

Comment: Can you give a [mre] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getRuleMetric` function from `inTrees`. According to the documentation of `inTrees`:

> Assign outcomes to a conditions, and measure the rules

Following your example with the iris dataset using `Species` as target:

```
ruleMetric <- getRuleMetric(ruleExec, X, target)
```

Output:

```
  #      len freq    err                  condition                                                                         pred        
  # [1,] "1" "0.333" "0"                  "X[,4]<=0.8"                                                                      "setosa"    
  # [2,] "3" "0.187" "0"                  "X[,4]>0.8 & X[,4]<=1.65 & X[,4]<=1.35"                                           "versicolor"
  # [3,] "4" "0.127" "0"                  "X[,3]<=4.95 & X[,4]>0.8 & X[,4]<=1.65 & X[,4]>1.35"                              "versicolor"
  # [4,] "5" "0.02"  "0"                  "X[,3]>4.95 & X[,4]>0.8 & X[,4]<=1.65 & X[,4]>1.35 & X[,4]<=1.55"                 "virginica" 
  # [5,] "6" "0.007" "0"                  "X[,2]<=2.85 & X[,3]>4.95 & X[,4]>0.8 & X[,4]<=1.65 & X[,4]>1.35 & X[,4]>1.55"    "versicolor"
  # [6,] "6" "0.007" "0"                  "X[,2]>2.85 & X[,3]>4.95 & X[,4]>0.8 & X[,4]<=1.65 & X[,4]>1.35 & X[,4]>1.55"     "virginica" 
  # ...
```